# Find the equation of the tangent to this curve

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm unsure what I have done is right or not, or my way of thinking.  Please let me know :)

'Find the equation of the normal to the curve $y = x^2 + 4x - 3$ at the point where the curve cuts the Y axis.

So first I'd write it in dy/dx form right?  So $2x^3 + 4$

Then I'd find the value to sub into X?  But what would that be?

Thanks

Comment: I think you mean $2x^{\color{red}{1}}+4$. And what is the $x$-value for _any_ point on the $y$-axis?

Comment: The curve cuts the Y axis when $x=0$. So you know the value to sub into X.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Curve cuts the Y axis" -- This means $x = 0$. $$\dfrac{dy}{dx} = 2x + 4$$

So at $x = 0$, $y' = 4$.

The gradient of the normal is $-\dfrac{1}{4}$

Can you go on from here?

Comment: Yes my bad, dydx incorrect!  And thank you!  If the curve cuts the X axis would that still be the same?

Comment: @Alex If the curve cuts the X axis, that means you have to find the zeroes of the equation and evaluate dydx at those points.

Comment: Thank you!  @Airdish!  If we were to say that the NORMAL of the curve, that would just be -1 / gradient correct?

Comment: @Alex Yes that is correct. This is because of the coord. geometry law for perpendicular lines $m_1m_2 = -1$.